# Linux: How to write the outputs of TWO terminal commands altogether into a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, io-redirection

Let's say i want to save (append) the outputs of commands:

- date
- free -m

.. into a file. With an expectation, like:

```
Thu Jan 14 04:38:08 GMT 2016
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:              3655       1087       2567          0         50        117
-/+ buffers/cache:            919        735
Swap:                0          0          0
```

I know the way to save with individual commands, like:

```
# date >> memlogs.txt
# free -m >> memlogs.txt
```

But how do i properly make them into one clean command please?

Comment: Can you confirm your shell? Since you're using Linux, one might assume bash, but a root prompt in csh/tcsh may have the `#` prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{ date; free -m; } > memlogs.txt
```

(Note the trailing semi-colon.)

or

```
{
    date
    free -m
} > memlogs.txt
```

or

```
exec > memlogs.txt
date
free -m
```

Surround the last one with parentheses to put the commands in a sub-shell if you want the redirection to be temporary.

```
(
    exec > memlogs.txt
    date
    free -m
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I like that first one, but with "double" arrows to "append" into file. `{ date; free -m; } >> memlogs.txt`.